# Symfony3 + Twig : Join array with <br/>

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-filter

I'm trying to display all elements inside an array and separate them with a line break, but I can't get it work.

Here is what I tried:

```
{{ user.roles | join('<br/>') }}
{{ user.roles | join('<br/>' | raw) }}
{{ user.roles | join('\n' | nl2br | raw) }}
```

Everytime I get something like:

> ROLE_PARENT<br/>ROLE_ADMIN<br/>ROLE_MANAGER<br/>ROLE_USER

How can I tell twig to render `<br/>` as html ?

I could loop through the array but it's not the first time I tried to render html tag and I would like a definitive solution to this problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A slight modification to your third attempt should do the trick as well.

```
{{ user.roles | join('\n')| nl2br  }}
```

Comment: Is the `| raw` necessary? Isn't `'\n' | raw` evaluated first and then `join()` on the result of it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the error, I'm not applying the filter at the right place, this works :

```
{{ user.roles | join('<br/>') | raw }}
```

Comment: Problem with this solution as opposed to the other one: if you have HTML tags in the original array's values, these will be rendered as well, due to applying `raw`. (Might be unimportant in this case, still thought it important to mention)

Answer (score 0):

What about a loop ?

https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

```
{%- for role in user.roles -%}
    {{- role -}}<br>
{%- endfor -%}
```

Note: You can manage whitespaces with `-`

https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control

Comment: Like I said in the post, I'm aware I could do a loop but this was not my question.

Answer (score 0):

{{ user.roles | join("\n") | nl2br | raw }}
This will work always

Docs
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/join.html

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/nl2br.html

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).